# How can I specify a default value for a log4j property

Tags: log4j

I want to have a single configuration that will run in multiple environments by changing a system property.  Following is an example:

```
log4j.appender.file.File=/opt/apps/${myEnvironment}/log/MyService.log
```

However, I want to make sure it still functions properly if someone forgets to set the system property.  Is there a way to specify a default value in the properties file?

Answer (score 3):

That might be possible. According to the API docs for `org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator`, your variable should first look for its value in the system properties, and if it is not found there, it should instead search through the configuration file.

> All option values admit variable substitution. The syntax of variable
>   substitution is similar to that of Unix shells. The string between an
>   opening "${" and closing "}" is interpreted as a key. The value of the
>   substituted variable can be defined as a system property or in the
>   configuration file itself. The value of the key is first searched in
>   the system properties, and if not found there, it is then searched in
>   the configuration file being parsed. The corresponding value replaces
>   the ${variableName} sequence. For example, if java.home system
>   property is set to /home/xyz, then every occurrence of the sequence
>   ${java.home} will be interpreted as /home/xyz.

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html

You will have to verify if the variable set in the configuration file would override the system properties though.